# Parsing data on 4th Octet

Tags: awk, dns, analysis

I have large files over 1 GB each.

They include 3 fields per record (tab delimited).

```
Src IP (tab) Dst IP (tab) DNS query
1.1.1.1 (tab) 2.2.2.2 (tab) test.com
1.2.3.1 (tab) 1.2.3.4 (tab) test.com
1.2.4.1 (tab) 9.8.7.6 (tab) bing.com
1.1.1.2 (tab) 2.2.2.2 (tab) test.com
9.8.7.2 (tab) 2.2.2.2 (tab) test.com
3.3.3.2 (tab) 2.2.2.2 (tab) bing.com
```

I would like to use AWK to count and list all DNS queries per the 4th octet of the src IP only. Thus output for above would look like the following:

```
4th octet (tab) DNS query (tab) count
.1 (tab) test.com (tab) 2
.1 (tab) bing.com (tab) 1
.2 (tab) test.com (tab) 1
.2 (tab) bing.com (tab) 2
```

I don't care about either the 1st, 2nd or 3rd octet of the Src IP address nor any part of the Dest IP address.

Only looking for a list of all DNS Queries with count per 4th octet of Src IP.

FWIW

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited my question, how is it?

Answer (score 1):

with `awk`

```
awk  '{split($1,a,"."); c[a[4] "\t" $3]++}
  END {for (i in c) print "." i "\t" c[i]}' file
```

Also you can pipe the output to `sort` for alphabetical or numeric (`-n`) sorting per any fields (`-k`).

input

```
1.1.1.1     2.2.2.2     test.com
1.2.3.1     1.2.3.4     test.com
1.2.4.1     9.8.7.6     bing.com
1.1.1.2     2.2.2.2     test.com
9.8.7.2     2.2.2.2     test.com
3.3.3.2     2.2.2.2     bing.com
```

output

```
.1      bing.com        1
.1      test.com        2
.2      bing.com        1
.2      test.com        2
```

Comment: That did it for the 4th octet and the domain query name, but there was no counter per DNS query name.

Comment: Please provide evidence for "there was no counter". What is the output you get? I have updated with testing and I see there is.

Comment: When I view the output on screen, I get the following:

Comment: .128    1b5c6744c930208b677678548b2b308d.clo.footprintdns.com
.237    8pgnlsflfx
.128    27g.trello.com
.128    4A1-623700.trello.com
.128    40b.pxl.ace.advertising.com
.96     4ppsforoffice.microsoft.com
.128    4s01.494700.xyz
.128    4s01.595700.xyz
.128    1ay.15010.xyzjp
.237    8zuvkplewk
.237    8esjljpsrmnk
.96     3SP-444100.trello.com
.96     1SP-185700.trello.com Edited to add: carriage returns seem to be stripped.

Comment: But when I redirect output to a file, I do get the counter, but it's on the following line below the output.

Comment: I think you have to provide the input as well. And probably update your question with that for readability.

Comment: @Walt sounds like you have `\r`s in your input file. Run `dos2unix` or similar on it first then try any of the posted solutions.

Comment: Yes, there are `\r`s at the end of input lines... so it's overwriting the existing line from `\r` and on.

Comment: I just performed a sed -i 's/\r//g' file.txt and fixed the output file. BTW, I couldn't find a dos2unix command under CYGWIN64. Regardless, problem is now solved. I want to thank everybody for their assistance.

Comment: You didn't have to do that on cygwin since there you're using GNU awk and so you could just set `-v RS='\r\n'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pipe of awk and uniq

```
awk -F'\t|\.' '{print "\t."$4"\t"$9"."$10}' infile | uniq -c | awk -F'\t' '{gsub(" ","",$1);print $2FS$3FS$1}'
```

Comment: I tried that, but ended up with: the following: $ awk -F'\t|\' '{print "\t."$4"\t"$9"."$10}' Test-1.txt | uniq -c | awk -F'\t' '{gsub(" ","",$1);print $2FS$3FS$1}'
.       .       5137285

Comment: And if I do it on the entire 1.5GB file, I get the following results: .       .       30,952,024
No output of either the 4th octet or the actual DNS query name. Edited to add: The total count does match in both cases though!

Answer (score 0):

If you have carriage return in your input file, you have to delete it before processing through awk:-

```
tr -d '\r' < file | awk '
        NR > 1 {
                I = $1
                sub ( /.*\./, ".", I )
                ++A[I OFS $3]
        }
        END {
                for ( k in A )
                        print k, A[k]
        }
' OFS='\t'
```

Comment: As mentioned above, I just performed sed -i 's/\r//g' file.txt and stripped the line feeds to get the output I was looking for.